# Determining the chromatic polynomial of a graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I would like to find the chromatic polynomial of this graph:

[image]

I know the chromatic polynomial $k(k - 1)^{n-1}$ for a tree. Also

$$p_{G}(k)= p_{G-e}(k) - p_{G\cdot e}(k) $$

is a recurrence I have. I also know the chromatic polynomial for $C_{n}$, the cycle graph.

I am new to this type of problem. I tried to use this recurrence almost 10 times but still make mistakes because I think the formula I am getting is wrong.

I don't know if there is a quicker way than what I am trying but I always first try to remove edge $(1, 5)$ and then keep going to reduce it into a path.

Can someone please help me? I think I am overcomplicating this problem. I keep on getting recurrences very very long and I guess I keep making mistakes (the polynomial I'm getting isn't even degree $7$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By thinking of $G$ as being obtained via a [2-clique-sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_polynomial#Properties) of $K_3$ and $C_5$ and then a 2-clique-sum of the result with $K_3$, you can compute
\begin{align}
p(G,x) 
&= \frac{p(K_3,x) p(C_5,x)}{x(x-1)}\cdot\frac{p(K_3,x)}{x(x-1)} \\
&= \frac{p(K_3,x)^2 p(C_5,x)}{x^2(x-1)^2} \\
&= \frac{(x(x-1)(x-2))^2((x-1)^5-(x-1))}{x^2(x-1)^2}\\
&=x(x-1)(x-2)^3(x^2-2x+2).
\end{align}

[A similar computation with $K_3$ in place of $C_5$](https://movies.supertran.net/2013/03/good-will-hunting-1997.html) appears in the 1997 movie [Good Will Hunting](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119217/).

Comment: Rob Pratt:  Confirmed by *Mathematica*.